# How to remove terracing from Civil3D GeoTIFF export?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, dem, civil3d

I've received a GeoTIFF DEM that was exported from `Civil3D` and at every contour there is a distinct terrace created when I process an aspect or slope in `QGIS` with the GRASS plugins.

[image: terracing]

I've looked around a bit and I think this is related to the algorithm used to create the DEM on the `Civil3D` side (Inverse Distance Weighting method).  Are there parameters within `Civil3D` to prevent this? or Is there a way to process the terraces out after the file is created in `QGIS`?

Answer (score 1):

Such problems can be overcome with point sampling and reinterpolation. See for example here: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't logged in for a while, thanks for the input though.  I ended up using r.neighbor and that seemed to work well.  I'll study up on the reference above.  Thanks!